# Trim JSONP date to extract year?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, jsonp

I'm using an API to retrieve data including the release date of a game;

```
 '<h4 style="display:inline-block; padding-left:5px;" class="post-title">' + game.name + ' <span class="small">' + game.original_release_date + '</span></h2>' +
```

I'm then outputting it to the page like so with game.original_release_date being the date. However I only need the year and it's in '2012-09-18 00:00:00' format.

How can I extract the year and display only that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var input = '2012-09-18 00:00:00';
var date  = new Date(input);
var year = date.getFullYear();
console.log(year);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date